# android how to play different video in one videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have this code wherein i will play different videos using one videoview only...

but because of i'm quite new to android programming i don't know how to use the setoncompletionlistener properly.. would you mind helping me in my problem..

here's my code..

I appreciate the help :))

```
package com.thesis.americansignlanguage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Videocompareclass extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    String get;
VideoView view;
int wordIndex = 0;
String[] getSplit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gesturecompare);
    Bundle gotWord = getIntent().getExtras();
    get = gotWord.getString("key");
    TextView Word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vd_view);
    Word.setText(get);
    view.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    getSplit = get.split(" ");

    String path = "/storage/sdcard1/video/" + getSplit[wordIndex] + ".mp4";
    wordIndex++;
    view.setVideoPath(path);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.start();

    view.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //  loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    view.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.d("error code", "whate: " + what +" extra"+extra);
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    });

    view.setOnCompletionListener(completeListener);
}

OnCompletionListener completeListener = new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.e("VideoPlayer", "OnComplete");
        if(get.length() >= wordIndex) {
        String path = "/storage/sdcard1/video/" + getSplit[wordIndex] + ".mp4";
        wordIndex++;
        view.setVideoPath(path);
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setOnCompletionListener(completeListener);
        view.start();
        }

        else {
             mp.release();
             finish();
        }
    }
};
}
```

here's the logcat is saying..
it has error like ArrayIndexOutofBounds..
i don't know how to fix it..

```
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at com.thesis.americansignlanguage.Videocompareclass$1.onCompletion(Videocompareclass.java:68)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.widget.VideoView$3.onCompletion(VideoView.java:381)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2075)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4800)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
03-26 20:46:19.047: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

us can set it like this :-

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer pMp) {
    Log.e("VideoPlayer", "OnComplete");
     // your logic here 
   }
});
```

Comment: sir can i ask you some help in building the logic??

Comment: yehey thanks.. would mind code some snippets of code?

Comment: i can tell u the approach !!

Answer (score 0):

// You can play only one video at a time ,if you want to play next video on completion of first video just use this method it will work.
// in on create should declare vdieo view

```
   public count = 0;
private void playVideo() {
    Log.d("check", "URL: "+url);
            int count= 0;                   
        String path = "/storage/extSdCard/video/" + getSplit[count] + ".mp4";
        count++;
    videoView.setVideoPath(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();  

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //  loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.d("error code","whate: "+ what +" extra"+extra);
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    });
     videoView.setOnCompletionListener(completeListner);
   }
          OnCompletionListener  completeListner = new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(videos.length() >= count) {  
               String path = "/storage/extSdCard/video/" + videos[count] + ".mp4";
               count++;
       videoView.setVideoPath(uri);
       videoView.requestFocus();
               videoView.setOnCompletionListener(completeListner);
       videoView.start();
                }
              else{
                     finish();
                   }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i do this. can it play different video?

Comment: because its like a converter that if i type a string of words..
the getSplit[] will contain the inputted words..

Comment: sir did you understand? :))

Comment: Yes i think when you call it after  getSplit = get.split(" "); it will play different

Comment: so in the oncompletion listener do i still need to put the code of yours?

Comment: if you want to play videos on finish of first video then you should.

Comment: videoView.setOnCompletionListener(completeListner); this part here has error sir.

Comment: it should be set after video start

Comment: OnCompletionListener  completeListner = new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(videos.length() >= count) {  
               String path = "/storage/extSdCard/video/" + videos[count] + ".mp4";
               count++;
       videoView.setVideoPath(uri);
       videoView.requestFocus();
       videoView.start();
       videoView.setOnCompletionListener(completeListner);
               }
              else{
                     finish();
                   }                
        }

Comment: sir somethings wrong after playing the video when it is finished. the app unfortunately closes.. i dont know why.

Comment: sir i saw the logcat and it says that the arrayIndex is out of bounds.

Comment: Actually remove = sign from if condition  if(get.length() > wordIndex) will solve your array index out of bound problem. And remove finish(); method in else condition , it will not close after last video played.